# How does the new "Brightness adjustment" setting work on CM11?

Tags: cyanogenmod, settings, screen-brightness

Cyanogenmod 11 has a new settings for Automatic brightness.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click to enlarge)</sup>

I am curious how exactly "Brightness adjustment" and "Adjustment sensitivity" work.

I tried to find the answer on Google and CM Wiki without success.

Comment: Man, this is still unanswered? Not knowing this is bugging me, I must do some research.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I went digging in the Cyanogen source code. It appears that settings work as follows:

- The brightness is determined from ambient light sensor based on spline (can be changed in "Adjust").
- **Brightness adjustment** - Makes overall auto-brightness result darker or lighter by affecting gamma value. Centering the slider means "no change".
- **Adjust to sunrise and sunset** - Also affects gamma value, but based on time of day and time of sunrise and sunset.
- **Adjustment sensitivity** - There is a delay in screen brightness changes due to ambient light changes. This settings affects the delay to make it faster / slower.

Comment: I love when features are only documented in the source code :(

Comment: I have really strange issue : setting brightness adjustment to 0 lux preview as it should but then when validating change the  luminosity change brigher.